# Sharepoint Wrkflow 2013 became doesn't work

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-workflow

The workflow suddenly stopped working on the site which had been operating for about a year ago.

With Office 365 Sharepoint,

The workflow was made by Sharepoint Designer and call HttpWebService to change authorities on list items.

I tried get the list item in Workflow 2013 on the test site as well, and it has stopped working the same way, so I am in trouble because I do not know the cause.

Massage is below.

> Activity in progress
>
> Retrying last request. Next attempt scheduled 2018/03/19 >13:18. Last request details: https: // 'site' / _ api / web / lists (guid >'GUID') / Items (242)? % 24 select = ID% 2 HTTP Unauthorized for CID

We grant the authority of the application with Full Control and activate "Use application privilege in workflow" in management of site function.

Even if it is not a solution, if there is a similar problem occurring, please share the information.

Comment: Has anything around permissions been changed in the site?  Also, the syntax of the error message looks odd:  guid >'GUID'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, It was an incident at the data center of Microsoft

Answer (score 0):

Please check if you have set valid header like this:

[image]

[image]

[image]